# wpdb->get_var always returning 0

Tags: plugin-development, sql

I am trying to run this statement:

```
global $wpdb;
$amt = $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare("SELECT SUM(amount) as amt FROM wp_pay_table WHERE postid = %i", $pid));
```

...but $amt always comes out as 0. I have checked that $pid is the correct value. I have also run the sql statement in my db and it returns the correct value (should be 75). I also tried get_row but had the same issue.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Where is $pid coming from? Can you echo out just the `$wpdb->prepare` part and let us know what it says?

Comment: Are you sure `postid = %i` and is not `%d` ?

Comment: czerspalace $pid was the post id passed in to the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`prepare` accepts [three placeholder arguments](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#Placeholders)-- " %s (string), %d (integer) and %f (float)". You have used `%i`.  That isn't going to get through the sanitization process. That is why you are getting `0`. You need `%d` instead.

Comment: Many thanks s_ha_dum you're right it should be %d. I was under the impression %i was integer and %d was decimal. I've no idea where I got that notion.